# Problem with ATI Catalyst Drivers in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, ati, 13.10, battery, fglrx

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8 (dual boot). My Laptop is Dell Inspiron 15, with AMD Radeon HD 7670 Video Card.

Without `fglrx` my expected battery life is reduced to 1:30 hrs from 3:30 hrs (In Ubuntu 13.04 but very slow booting).

So I installed fglrx using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775).

But the problem is as you all know, **Black Screen after logging** into Ubuntu.

Tried so many solutions for this like reinstalling `unity`, `ubuntu-desktop`, `compizconfig`, etc. But none helped except removing `fglrx*` completely. (But I need them very badly due to battery)

PS. For those who think this question is a duplicate. Though the question may be a duplicate, but the answer is not!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [BETA drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx). Ubuntu 13.10 is using Xserver 1.14 (supported by AMD BETA Drivers) and as far as I know the official drivers' support Xserver up to 1.13.

Using the automatic install using that setup file has worked for me or you can use the same guide that you referenced in your question.

Comment: Fortunately, I've been trying on the same beta drivers that you linked in your answer from 2 days :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use try to use the Ubuntu AMD Catalyst install that you can find here :
http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install

It's a nice apprication that could help you to install the proper AMD driver for your hardware.

> The application auto detects your ATI / AMD graphics hardware and selects the best driver options to install.
>   This application downloads, creates DEB packages and installs the latest AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Display Drivers for Ubuntu 32bit/64bit.
>   You can also install the latest AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Display BETA Drivers as well as Legacy AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Display Drivers if your hardware is supported.

Comment: Continuously getting the error message that "Downloaded file contains errors" though it is not even starting the download

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying nomodeset or any of the other options at boot?

It may be possible you might also need the fglrx-updates and catalyst-updates packages instead of just flgrx and catalyst.  I had to use the "updates" for my video card to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found frustration so far with the fglrx drivers in Xubuntu 13.10.  However, for battery life improvement, check this out:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html.  This helped battery and sleep/wake issues, but I still would like to make fglrx work so I can use my HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I don't know if you found a solution or if its still an issue, but this is what I encountered and how I fixed it.. its a little sloppy but it beats reinstalling.  [ati 6770 on ubuntu 13.10 with xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381811/ati-6770-on-ubuntu-13-10-with-xfce)

Answer (score 0):

This is my current kernel:

> Linux version 3.11.0-15-generic (buildd@batsu) (gcc version 4.8.1
>   (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) ) #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04
>   UTC 2013

Ubuntu 13.10

If you haven't updated your Ubuntu, update it first.

Then follow [this guide](https://gist.github.com/moldcraft/8116528).

This is what I did

- Download amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
  [AMD Site For Linux 64Bit](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.zip)
- Extract it and you will get amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run
- chmod +x amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run
- run the code below to extract the installation files in catalyst directory
- ./amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run --extract catalyst
- cd catalyst
- vim ./common/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/kcl_acpi.c
- go to line 990 and delete every thing till the end of the file
- Paste these code and save it:

```
    #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3,6,3)    
        if (!ACPI_SUCCESS(acpi_get_table_with_size(id, 0, &hdr, &tbl_size)))
    #else
        tbl_size = 0x7fffffff;
        if (!ACPI_SUCCESS(acpi_get_table(id, 0, &hdr)))
    #endif
        {
            return KCL_ACPI_ERROR;
        }
    #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3,9,1)
        ((acpi_tbl_table_handler)handler)(hdr);
    #else
        ((acpi_table_handler)handler)(hdr);
    #endif
        return KCL_ACPI_OK;
    }
```

- sudo ./ati-installer.sh 13.251 --install  (I DID NOT FOLLOW THE INSTRUCTION, I INSTALL IT DIRECTLY)

Then reboot the system, I reboot the system twice then everything is ok! Yeah!

Comment: Anyway, installing the ATI Driver also will reduce the battery usage, my battery can last 2Hour with Internet usage. I installed fglrx before, but is not that good, I had problem switching to the Intel Graphics too. Just get the latest Driver from AMD and install.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Dell laptop and here is how I solved the problem.

I found this tool useful: http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install

But I think you can use other methods described on askubuntu. 
After you get black screen you should do the following (instruction from site above):

Drop to terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Login with your username and password

Then enter :

```
sudo aticonfig --initial --adapter=all    
sudo reboot now
```

Worked for me!